# Rails: Default Value - select field

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to display a default select value. What I have so far is:

`<%= f.collection_select(:user_id, User.where(brand: current_user.brand), :id, :name, {prompt:true}, {class: 'form-control'}, :selected => current_user.brand) %>`

But this produces an error:

> wrong number of arguments (7 for 4..6)

Any ideas what the problem is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
<%= f.collection_select(:user_id, User.where(brand: current_user.brand), :id, :name, {prompt: true}, {class: 'form-control', selected: current_user.brand}) %>
```

`selected` should be in the `html_options`. See also:
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-collection_select